# SharePoint 2007 Custom Data View and Modified Date

Tags: sharepoint-designer

What I am trying to accomplish is identify when the modfied date of a record is current to 6 days old, 7 to 13 days old and then older than 13 days.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the XSL of your DVWP, establish a variable that is a formatted date of the modified column. Do the same for today's date. Then figure out the equation to test it. Then perform a when/otherwise to decide what to display.

```
<xsl:variable name="modifiedDate" select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Modified), 1033, 1)" />
<xsl:variable name="todaysDate" select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(Today()), 1033, 1)" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$todaysDate &lt;= ($modifiedDate  + 6)">6 days old</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="($todaysDate &lt;= ($modifiedDate  + 13)) and ($todaysDate &gt;= ($modifiedDate + 6))>7-13 days old</xsls:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>More than 13 days old</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I'm not sure if this is the exact syntax but this is the theory you need to get it working.

Comment: Date math in XSLT is ridiculously more difficult than the syntax provided above...

Comment: This is true. I didn't test the code. It's more of a theory to find the right syntax than a literal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without SPD as well. Check this link for pointers - http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=8d9e2a99-f288-47c2-916b-2f32864f7b82&ID=512&Web=5e4647a0-e7d0-4626-b71c-b1ff06402465